# Pinch Gesture in Swift Playground?

Tags: swift-playground, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Initially I read you couldn't experiment with touches or gestures in a playground.  Then I found that touchesMoved or a tap gesture would react.  However, I now am testing a UIPinchGestureRecognizer.  There isn't the feature that lets you simulate two fingers with the alt key in the playground.  Are you telling me I have to create an Xcode project and compile and run for each iteration simply because its a pinch and not a tap?

Answer (score 0):

**As of 2020:**

Option + Shift will do the trick. You might have to click into the live view first but then it should work.